# wine is not working. Unhandled loader error: 8

Tags: .net, linux, mono, wine, winexe

i am trying to run a program through wine but it giving me a error

```
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" not implemented
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"dependentAssembly" in state 0
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"assemblyIdentity" in state 6
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"bindingRedirect" in state 6
Unknown heap type: #GUlD

Unknown heap type: #Blop

Can't find custom attr constructor image: C:\Program Files (x86)\hide.me VPN\Hide.me.exe mtoken: 0x0a00000e
Unhandled loader error: 8, (null) PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 (null)
* Assertion: should not be reached at ../../../mono/mono/metadata/loader.c:299
```

i want to know, what is the source of error and how can i eliminate it.
i tried to search online but don't found anything. any help/suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: i want to know that what is the source of error

Comment: Please show the relevant source code. In this case, I believe it is your app's manifest file.

Comment: hey jww is their a way ,- that i can send you private message ? so that i can give you my team viewer login information